# pg_search gem and fulltext search rank setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

Im using the gem [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) to perform fulltext search on my postgres db.
I've a scope like this:

```
pg_search_scope :fulltext, against: [:firstname, :lastname, :middlename],
                using: {
                  tsearch: { prefix: true },
                    trigram: {
                      :threshold => 0.2
                    }
                  }
```

When i search with the string *gro* I would like that the records that match the exactly word *gro* have rank higher than records that match words like *group* (*group* contain *gro*).

Any idea, if there are some settings to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a very similar situation in Django and I solved summing up the trigram similarity and tsearch rank.

Similarity with word with exact match is higher than a partial match, as you can check on PostgresSQL:

```
SELECT similarity('gro', 'gro') AS exact, similarity('gro', 'group') AS partial;
 exact | partial  
-------+----------
     1 | 0.428571
```

I'm not a ruby expert but I've read the [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#ranked_by-choosing-a-ranking-algorithm) documentation and I think the solution for your question should by similar to this:

```
pg_search_scope :fulltext,
                against: [:firstname, :lastname, :middlename],
                using: {
                  tsearch: { prefix: true },
                  trigram: {
                      :threshold => 0.2
                  }
                },
                :ranked_by => ":tsearch + :trigram"
```